# Como remover uma linha de um arquivo de texto

Tags: python, arquivo, python-2.7, tkinter

Olá. Estou a criar um programa que abre, guarda ou elimina links. No entanto, apesar de conseguir remover o item seleccionado da lista de links não consigo eliminar a linha do arquivo que corresponde ao item seleccionado. Pesquisei no SOEN e não encontrei resultados esclarecedores e o fileinput também não resultou. Código:

```
    # -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
from Tkinter import *
import threading
import urllib
import webbrowser
import os
import fileinput

root = Tk()

root.focus_force()

#define o tamanho da janela:
root.minsize(700,500)
root.maxsize(700,500)

#variaveis globais:
global texto_link
global meter_links
global listbox

#variavel de continuação de funçoes:
hiperlink = True
hipertrue = True
supertrue = True

#vaiavel de atualizacao:
atualiza = True

#lista temporária de links:
lista = []

#titulo da janela
root.title("Links Úteis - FastLabPyTool")

#icone do canto:
root.wm_iconbitmap('icone.ico')

#texto auxiliar:
def texto_auxiliar():
    texto_link = Label(root, text = "Insere aqui o Link:", font = "Arial 10")
    texto_link.place(x = 30, y = 50)
texto_auxiliar()

#insere caixas de texto:
meter_links = Entry(root, width = 70, fg = "blue")
meter_links.place(x = 150, y = 50)

#Ficheiro:
filename = "linkers.txt"

#coloca a lista de links:
def lista_links(f, line, item):
    listbox = Listbox(root, width = 105, height = 20, bg = "cyan", fg = "blue")
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        f = f.readlines()
        for line in f:
            listbox.insert(END, line)
        listbox.bind('<Button-3>', lambda event: eventos_linkers(event, line, f, listbox, line, item))  
    listbox.place(x = 20, y = 100)
lista_links(hiperlink, hipertrue, supertrue)

#conecta o link à internet:
def link_conections(listbox):
    items = listbox.curselection()
    for item in items:
        item = listbox.get(item)
        webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open(item)

#apaga os links seleccionados do arquivo:
def delete_links_arq(listbox, line, item):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    f = open(filename, "w")
    for line in lines:
        if item in line:
            f.write(item.replace(line, ''))
            f.close()

    """for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
        if ( line):
           continue
        print (line, end='')"""

#apaga os links:
def delete_links(listbox, items, f, line, item):
    items = listbox.curselection()
    for item in items:
        listbox.delete(item, item)
        items = listbox.curselection()
        item = listbox.get(item)
        delete_links_arq(listbox, line, item)       

#abre opções de linker através de eventos:
def eventos_linkers(event, items, f, listbox, line, item):
    link_options = ["Abrir Hiperligação", "Eliminar Hiperligação"]
    menu_options = Menu(root)
    menubar = Menu(root, tearoff = 0)
    menubar.add_cascade(label = link_options[0], command = lambda: link_conections(listbox))
    menubar.add_cascade(label = link_options[1], command = lambda: delete_links(listbox, items, f, line, item))
    menubar.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)

#decide se a caixa de texto contem um link:
def links_name(f, line, item):
    texto = meter_links.get()
    abrir = open(filename, "a")
    if (len(str(texto))) > 0:
        abrir.write((texto) + "\n")
        abrir.close()
        texto = 0
        lista_links(f, line, item)
links_name(hiperlink, hipertrue, supertrue)

#coloca os botoes:
def botoes(f, line, item):
    botao_submit = Button(root, text = "Guardar Link", bg = "cyan", fg = "black", command = lambda: links_name(f, line, item))
    botao_submit.place(x = 600, y = 45)
botoes(hiperlink, hipertrue, supertrue)

#Apenas se valer mesmo a pena :)
"""
#cria um proceso no CPU:
def processo():
    try:
        processar = thread.start_new_thread( print_time, ("Thread-1", 2, ) )
        processar.start()
    except:
        print "ERRO: Impossível criar processo!"
processo()
"""
#acaba o programa:
root.lift()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Provavelmente você vai ter que gerar o arquivo novamente, sem a linha que quer apagar, ou então, para uma melhor performance, marcar a linha como inutilizada (trocando o primeiro caractere por algum simbolo especial) e reaproveitando a linha futuramente, para dados que couberem. Mas de quando em quando teria que desfragmentar este arquivo, no 2o caso.

Comment: E se eu tentasse substituir a linha que quero apagar por uma string em branco?

Comment: Nao  -a abrodagem correta é re-escrever o arquivo sem a linha que vocẽ quer - esqueça essa história de tentar reaproveitar a linha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na função `eventos_linkers` onde você tem:

```
menubar.add_cascade(label = link_options[1], 
command = lambda: delete_links(listbox, items, f, line, item))
```

Remova o `lambda` pois ele não é necessário neste caso.

Na função `delete_links` você tem o seguinte:

```
#apaga os links:
def delete_links(listbox, items, f, line, item):
    items = listbox.curselection()
    for item in items:
        listbox.delete(item, item)            # Aqui você deleta o item selecionado
        items = listbox.curselection()
        item = listbox.get(item)              # E aqui você acha que obtem o item selecionado
        delete_links_arq(listbox, line, item) # Por fim, você passa um valor errado aqui
```

Para que a função funcione como desejado, faça o seguinte:

```
#apaga os links:
def delete_links(listbox, items, f, line, item):
    items = listbox.curselection()
    for index in items:
        item = listbox.get(index)             # Obtem o item selecionado
        items = listbox.curselection()
        listbox.delete(index)                 # Deleta o item

        delete_links_arq(listbox, line, item) # Aqui você passa o valor correto
```

A função `delete_links_arq` por sua vez também tem alguns equívocos.

```
#apaga os links seleccionados do arquivo:
def delete_links_arq(listbox, line, item):
    f = open(filename, "r")    # Abre em modo somente leitura
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    f = open(filename, "w")    # Abre em modo de escrita
    for line in lines:
        if item in line:
            f.write(item.replace(line, '')) # Aqui você não está removendo a linha
            f.close()          # Fecha o arquivo precocemente

    """for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
        if ( line):
           continue
        print (line, end='')"""
```

Usando a abordagem com o `Fileinput` você pode escrever essa função assim:

```
#apaga os links seleccionados do arquivo:
def delete_links_arq(listbox, line, item):
    for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
        if item in line:        # Se o link estiver nessa linha então faça
            pass                # Não faz nada, pula
        else:                   # Se não
            print(line, end='') # Escreve a linha no arquivo
```

O `inplace=True` faz com que a saída padrão seja redirecionada para o arquivo, permitindo reescreve-lo sem precisar colocar o ponteiro no início do arquivo ou zerá-lo.

Com essas modificações o seu código deverá funcionar do modo esperado.

> <sub>*Ainda vou tentar melhorar a resposta..*</sub>

Comment: Obrigado :) Parece que resultou. Só tive que manter o lambda no código visto que o programa estava a apagar o link seleccionado ao clicar apenas no lado direito do rato sem mostrar o menu de opções.